# MSBuild Package Location

Tags: msbuild, package, msdeploy

When I run MSBuild with the /t:Package parameter I want to be able to specify where the folder that contains the *.cmd and *.zip files gets output. Specifying _PackageTempDir outputs the entire application without the deploy files (*.cmd and *.zip). Is there any way to specify this in the command line?

**UPDATE:**
The OutDir param outputs more than I need or want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you set

```
<DesktopBuildPackageLocation>c:\foo\MyProject.zip</DesktopBuildPackageLocation>
```

you'll get the .zip file, the .cmd file, and the other related output files in c:\foo.

Comment: Where do you set DesktopBuildPackageLocation?

Comment: @jcolebrand on the command line, with /p:DesktopBuildPackageLocation=your/path.  In VS2010, in the project file with the XML snippet above.  Just make sure it's under the right section for your configuration/platform.  In VS2012, in the .pubxml file for your publish profile.

Comment: I followed some documentation but still not getting it worked out. Will try some more stuff tomorrow and update this answer if I remember once I know more about where I would like to see it set if I was asking in the future in the CSPROJ XML

Answer (score 9):

I've found that setting /p:DesktopBuildPackageLocation=some\package.zip for MSBuild doesn't work (it works when specified in pubxml though).

However, it turns out that setting /p:PackageFileName=some\package.zip works fine. Furthermore, you can use it along with /p:PublishProfile parameter.